# ruby: gem build... how do i include vendor directory in gem?

Tags: ruby

I run `gem build mygem.gemspec` and the vendor dir is not included. How do I include it in my gem? I am assuming that I need the vendor dir included if I want to package all the dependencies with my gem.

I think it has to do with `Dir['vendor/**']`... I know that is wrong.

My gemspec file:

```
lib = File.expand_path('../lib', __FILE__)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(lib) unless $LOAD_PATH.include?(lib)
require 'fpa/fix_filename/version'

Gem::Specification.new do |spec|
  spec.name          = "fpa-fix_filename"
  spec.version       = Fpa::FixFilename::VERSION
  spec.authors       = ["na"]
  spec.email         = ["na"]

  spec.summary       = %q{A Class to fix bad file names -- includes a binary for command line use.}
  spec.description   = %q{}
  spec.license       = "MIT"

  spec.files = Dir['lib/fpa/**/*'] + Dir['bin/*'] + Dir['vendor/**']

  spec.bindir        = "bin"
  spec.executables   = spec.files.grep(%r{^bin/}) { |f| File.basename(f) }

  spec.require_paths = ["lib"]

  spec.add_runtime_dependency "micro-optparse", "~> 1.2.0"

  spec.add_development_dependency "bundler", "~> 1.8"
  spec.add_development_dependency "rake", "~> 10.0"
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried like this ?

```
Dir['vendor/**/*']
```

Comment: Ah... you know what... I did, but I see now I had a syntax error and assumed it was because the vendor directory was more than two dirs deep and I needed another way to address deeper directories.  Thanks